# Retain the list of the properties of a class

Tags: javascript, babeljs, decorator, javascript-decorators

I'm creating annotations to add functionalities to some classes at runtime, like the following:

```js
const anno = function () {
    return function (Class, descriptor) {
      // can I have the list of properties here?
    }
};

@anno()
class App {
   property = "hello";
}
```

Is there a way to retain the list of the properties of a class in javascript with Babel (with some plugins for example) so I could use it inside an annotation?

Comment: Which version of decorators are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version "2022-03" of `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`